# Air for ios app weird size issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

So i updated to the newest flash version and started using Air for ios 3.4. That's great, now i can properly auto orient the screen and always keep it in landscape easily. BUT for some reason the app is just one fourth of the screen and is in the upper left corner with the rest of the screen being white.

Here is an image of the problem: [[http://i.imgur.com/i4ZSt39.jpg][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02FBI.jpg)

Before, with air 3.2 the size was right and i have no idea what caused this with air 3.4. All the grapichs are 1024*768

Any help will be deeply appreciated

Comment: have you tried setting `percentHeight` and `percentWidth` to 100? (or `height/width = "100%"` in mxml?

Comment: @CyanAngel  Thanks for replying. uhm, i cant find percentHeight and width. Is it supposed to be in the xml file? Can't find it

Answer (score 0):

I believe 3.3 or 3.4 is the version that fixed support for retina displays. Prior to that, all AIR versions reported the retina iPads as non-retina.

You should make sure that `<requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>` is found in your app.xml in the iOS Additions section.

Additionally, you need to make sure that you are not using static values for your app's sizing. Non-Retina iPads are 1024x768 (the resolution your app is using, I believe), but Retina iPads are 2048x1536. Your positioning and sizing should be completely fluid and responsive and never rely on fixed sizes. Instead of setting a Sprite's width to 1024 to fill the entire screen, you should instead use `stage.stageWidth`, for example.

Word to the wise, though: if you want to submit to the App Store, you're going to need **at least** the most recent release of AIR 4.0. iOS 7 requires new icon sizes that weren't added until 3.8 or 3.9 and all apps are now required to be compiled using XCode 5, something that AIR 4.0 added support for. For the record, we are currently on AIR 13.0 (after 4.0, version numbering system was changed to a rapid release system and bumped to 13.0 to make it match Flash Player)